# A software for adjusting touch screen options

Tags: touchscreen

I am using a laptop with a touch-screen, and I am looking for a software that will allow me to customize the touch screen options. For example, I want firefox to scroll down when I'm touching the screen and drag my finger up (like in laptops with Windows 8). Is there any program that allows me to do that?
Thank for answering!

Comment: Please mention your version of Ubuntu and the desktop environment you are using. That would help people answer. (Also, in my HUMBLE opinion, touch screen support will get better from Unity 8. So be patient! :-D )

Answer (score 0):

I found a [blogpost](http://mydevelopedworld.wordpress.com/2013/11/30/how-to-configure-new-lenovo-x240-touchpad-on-ubuntu-13-10/) concerning modifications of the sensitivity of a touchpad of a notebook under ubuntu 13.10, but I think that your problem is related to that one or can be solved in a similar way.

What is proposed in the blog is an edit of the touch driver configuration, which should be synaptic.

```
$ sudo vim /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synapticconf
```

In that file you will probably need to add an event for long-presses, if it is not there yet.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! But what does that "vim" in the beginning mean?

Comment: @Hagaymosko vim is just the editor I usually use. You can use gedit or any other editor instead.

Comment: OK. I encountered another problem: Ubuntu doesn't allow me to save that file although I changed its permissions.

Comment: @Hagaymosko how did you open the file? I am pretty sure that it would work if you used the `vim` ;)